# How can I center a button in the cell of a table using CSS ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am learning HTML and CSS and I am really struggling with how to get my CSS to work on the objects in my HTML.  Specifically how to center a button in the cell of a table.  I have:

```
#LeftButton {
   margin:auto;
   display:block;
}  

<asp:table runat="server" ID="outerTable">
            <asp:TableRow>
                 <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbLeftLabel" runat="server" Text="Resources NOT opening early"></asp:Label>
                 </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbRightLabel" runat="server" Text="Resources opening 1 hour early"></asp:Label>
                 </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="300px" DataSourceID="RISDataSource" DataTextField="DisplayValue" DataValueField="EntryCode" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Table runat="server" ID="innerTable">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="RightButton" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="32px" ImageUrl="~/Images/right.png" BackColor="#efefef" BorderStyle="None" Enabled="False" OnClick="RightButton_Click" />
                        </asp:TableCell>
                     </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="LeftButton" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="32px" ImageUrl="~/Images/left.png" BackColor="#efefef" BorderStyle="None" Enabled="False" OnClick="LeftButton_Click"/>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                     </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
               <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="300px" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ListBoxRIS_IC_WORK" DataTextField="DisplayValue" DataValueField="EntryCode" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:table>
```

But my CSS does not appear to be doing anything. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<table border='1' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td class="centerBtn">
            <button type="button"> test </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.centerBtn {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly, just not on my page for some reason.  I must have done something else wrong...

Comment: This ended up working well too: 
I added this to the TableCell and it centered my ImageButton.

    <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" style="padding: 0px;">
        <asp:ImageButton/>
    </asp:TableCell>
Found my answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1418752.aspx?image+button+inside+table+cell